# How to get the current permissions for an MSMQ private queue?

Tags: powershell, permissions, msmq, system.messaging

Does anybody know how to read the user\group access permissions from an MSMQ private queue in powershell? I'd like to do this as a sanity check for my deployment script that installs NServiceBus services to make sure the service user actually has read access to the appropriate queue before installing the service.

From the documentation on the System.Messaging.MessageQueue class it seems like there are plenty of methods to set permissions for a queue, but no methods to get the permissions.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

-Jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no .net method to retrieve actual ACL on a msmqueue.

You need to do some P/invoke::[MQGetQueueSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here  c# code to add-type in powershell::[pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mqrt/MQGetQueueSecurity.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response... That was kind of what I was expecting, but hoping to avoid. My only other thought is that I might try to impersonate the service user and do a peek on the queue, then catch any errors.

Comment: I finally got around to writing a small library to solve this problem. https://github.com/jlevitt/MSMQSecurity

Comment: Hi - I downloaded your class library. Seems as though you need to know the username before you can get their ACL on the MSMQ queue. I am trying to build a utility program that clones existing queues.  Therefore I don't know what usernames have been granted access to the existing queue.  Is there any way to get a list of those usernames?

Comment: @JakeLevitt - Hi - I downloaded your class library. Seems as though you need to know the username before you can get their ACL on the MSMQ queue. I am trying to build a utility program that clones existing queues. Therefore I don't know what usernames have been granted access to the existing queue. Is there any way to get a list of those usernames?